# which is better for operate db from java jdbc

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc

that's a question which has confuse me a lot.
for example:
when I design the Dao layer,sometimes,I must do some insert operation,and than
I should do some query such as select the data's id by auto-generate in db.
my question was that:
when I use spring to help manage datasource,
when I do more than two sql operation one by one,
how many times the java client connect to the db?? only one ? or more?
code,such as fellows:

```
getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(some params...);
getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(some params...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your `Transactional` settings.

Spring-transactions in local mode, work on a thread-local connection for all the db activities within single transaction.

If you have not configured transactions, then basically each DB call will retrieve connection from datasource using `Datasource.getConnection()`

In terms client connecting to DB, if you are using datasource with connection pooling capability, then connections are returned from the pool.

But if datasource is not backed by pool, then it will instantiate connection to DB server on demand ( on getConnection() ) call

Comment: yep,I have not configured transactions. so ,the times, client connect to DB was depended on the capability of the pooling??

Comment: @alardear that's correct, If you have not configured a datasource backed by pool, then its going to DB server on every call.